# Find basis of kernel and image of linear transformation given by matrix in basis

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For linear transformation $ T: R^4 \to F_{w,2}(R, R)$ given by matrix

\begin{split}
A = A(T)_{B',B}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 0 & -1 \\
2 & -2 & 1 & -4 \\
-2 & 2 & -2 & 2
\end{bmatrix}
\end{split}

For:

\begin{split}
B = {\{ \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} \}}
\end{split}
\begin{split}
B' = (1, 1+x, 1+x+x^2)
\end{split}

Find basis of $ Ker \space T $ and $ Im \space T $.

I transform matrix to upper triangular and from that i got base of $ Im T $ equal:

\begin{split}
\{\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 2 \\ -2
\end{bmatrix},
\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\ 1 \\ -2
\end{bmatrix}\}
\end{split}

But I don't know if that's appropriate approach. Could someone explain me how to solve that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Check my edit please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track when it comes to finding a basis for $\text{im}(T)$. The vectors which you found are the coordinate vectors with respect to $B'$ of the basis vectors which you want. To get the basis vectors which you want, left multiply each of the vectors which you found by the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$
Note that the first column corresponds to $1$, the second column to $1+x$ and the third column to $1+x+x^2$. Then convert the resulting vectors into their corresponding polynomial. That is, 
$$\begin{pmatrix} a\\ b\\ c\end{pmatrix}$$
corresponds to $a+bx+cx^2$. To find a basis for $\text{ker}(T)$, do a similar thing. First find a basis for $\text{ker}(A)=\{x:Ax=0\}$ and then left multiply each of the basis vectors by the matrix 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$